# Trigger the Function Automatically in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

In my ASP.NET Application, there is an If Condition on `Details.cshtml` page, which looks for the state, if it's `Requested`, it will enable the Button, and by manually clicking the Button, `ProcessRequest()` function will be triggered.

I want to make this Process automatically, e.g. if the Condition is Requested, triggered the `ProcessRequest` without clicking the Button, manually.

**Details.cshtml**

```
@if (Model.State == CredentialState.Requested)
{
    <tr>
    <td>
    <a role="button" asp-controller="Credentials" asp-action="ProcessRequest" asp-route-id="@Model.CredentialRecordId">Send credential</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**CredentialsController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessRequest(string id)
{
    // Code
}
```

Comment: Why not do that in the controller? Showing the view seems unnecessary if you were able to determine that the condition was true when you built the model, long before showing the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called "[Redirect](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/2cde4c7c-b43d-4c67-acc2-614ae9b0fcf5.aspx)", do it from Controller/Action "Details".

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(string id) // from action "Details"
{
    // code to get Model first
    ...
    // check Model.State
    if (Model.State == CredentialState.Requested)
    {
      //return await ProcessRequest(Model.CredentialRecordId); //as madreflection suggested

      return RedirectToAction("ProcessRequest", "Credentials", new { id = Model.CredentialRecordId}); //redirect with your own function.
    }

    return View(Model);
}
```

Comment: Or avoid the round trip and call it directly: `return await ProcessRequest(id);`

Comment: @madreflection I didn't debug, just write code here. maybe he already know how to do it with this way. hehe

Comment: thanks to both of you, it worked.. but I have to click on the record for it to Issue the Credentials (previously, I have to open the detail page and click on the button, thanks for simplifying it). I want that if I refresh the Page, it issued all the credentials, where the state is requested. thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Dongdong is there any way to issue the credential without any interaction?

Comment: Actually I dont understand what credential it is. you might need a new post to detail your question. but for now, if you want  your page smoothly get back to "Details" page after "ProcessRequest", you can do this:`return RedirectToAction("ProcessRequest", "Credentials", new { id = Model.CredentialRecordId, returnUrl=$"details/{id}"});`, then use `Redirect(returnUrl);` from action `ProcessRequest`.@IngmarBergman